# Android front camera preview has narrower angle

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing a camera filter app, and my aim is to have a square camera preview (crop it, and get the center square), and take photos as square.

I am using the Google API's getOptimalPreviewSize method, which is:

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null) return null;
    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int targetHeight = h;
    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }
    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

I am testing on an LG G4 device, and there is no problem with the back-facing camera. All the apps (Retrica, Instagram, device's Camera app) including mine are showing the same preview. But, when it comes to front facing camera, then Instagram and Retrica has wider angle, and device's Camera app and my application has narrower angle.

I don't know how to fix this, because even when I get the preview as 1920*1080 (maximum available size for front camera), the preview is like "zoomed in".

Any suggestions how to fix this problem? (my app is showing exact scene that the device's Camera app shows, but Instagram-Retrica shows kinda zoomed-out scene.

Thank you.

(PS: My application is getting preview on SurfaceView, the typical way)